# How to change the PDF fileName to file Name as it display Function name as FileName in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, filenames

I wanted to display pdf file name as the filename but it display function name as file Name.Below is the set of code

```
        public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetPDF(string FileName, string DocName)
        {
                CloudFile file = Utility.CloudAzureFile(DocName, FileName, ".pdf");
                string Cloudfilename = file.Uri.ToString();
                if (file.Exists())
                {
                    var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
                }
return null;
            }
```

I have tried below two approaches to show but in both way it is opening an download dialoge box.

```
return File(stream, "application/pdf", FileName);
```

and

```
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+DocName);
    //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", FileName.ToString());
 return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

Editied:
[image: Image: how its displays]

Answer (score 0):

```
        public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetPDF(string FileName, string DocName)
        {
                CloudFile file = Utility.CloudAzureFile(DocName, FileName, ".pdf");
                string Cloudfilename = file.Uri.ToString();
                if (file.Exists())
                {
                    var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                    var result = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
                    result=.FileDownloadName = FileName + ".pdf";
                    return result;
                }
              return null;
        }
```

Try this piece of code this is working for me hope it help.

Comment: Getting an error as FileStreamResult cannot be used as method.

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot to initialize the object. Try it now.

Comment: Still the same... Pdf is not displayed insteed  it opens file downloading dialogue box

Comment: your above problem of function name as filename is resolved or not? check if the downloaded file is ok.

Comment: My problem is not with file downloading... I had displayed a pdf in the web page but its name is been displayed as function name not as the file name. and was facing an issue to display file name over there. Added an image how it displays..

Comment: is the file name fixed or it changes. if it is fixed you can change method name. may be it is because of parsing the stream data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205231/discussion-between-rajan-mishra-and-beena-gupta).